# Open source server that runs Android apps and makes them available via a Web UI

Tags: android, open-source, virtualization, amazon

I'm looking for something to virtualize Android apps, similar to Amazon AppStore's TestDrive.
According to Amazon their TestDrive is powered by EC2 where the clicks and buttons are captured and processed in their EC2 instances, and all video and sound is sent back to the web UI.

Must be open source.

Comment: Please say why Amazon's solution is not good for you, otherwise we can't help you. Too expensive? You need more features? (if yes please detail)

Comment: I made the requirements stricter so that this question becomes on-topic (it would be closed as too vague if not). Feel free to change it to other requirements.